# Keep the highest results after a rolling function but without intersecting windows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a way to perform a rolling function in Pandas, and keep a specific value, for example the highest or lowest, and then removing all other windows intersecting that range.

Imagine for example a year of temperature measurements, and you want to know the warmest 20-day periods that have occurred. The absolute warmest is easy, perform a rolling function and sort the result. But given the nature of how temperature changes, the second, third etc will likely be the same period with just a 1-day shift in window. Which is what i want to avoid, and so only end up with unique, non-intersecting, periods.

I have found one workaround which is listed below, but it involves loops, storing results in a list and recreating a DataFrame, its far from fancy. So i am curious if anyone knows a more Pythonic way of handling these situations.

Sample data can be created with:

```
window = 20

end = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2014-01-01', end='2014-12-31', freq='D')
begin = end.shift(-(window - 1))

df = pd.DataFrame({'begin': begin,
                   'end': end,
                   'values': np.sin(np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, len(begin))) * 10.})

df['values'] = pd.rolling_mean(df['values'], window)
df = df.dropna()
```

This gives a year of dummy data minus the first 19-days which get lost due to missing values in the window.

My approach is as follows:

```
# sort the DataFrame so the 'to keep' values are at the beginning, in this case highest
# 'values' first. But an alternative way of ordering could be used of course.

df.sort('values', ascending=False, inplace=True)

# a list to store rows
keep = []

# loop until there are no rows left in the DataFrame
while len(df) > 0:

    # select the top row
    toprow = df.iloc[0]

    # store it
    keep.append(toprow)

    # get the range of the tow
    end = toprow.end
    begin = toprow.begin

    # boolean mask for all ranges intersecting the selected range
    before = (df.end >= begin) & (df.end <= end)
    after = (df.begin >= begin) & (df.begin <= end)

    # remove all other values intersecting with the range
    df = df[~(before | after)]

# merge the stored rows (Series) to a DataFrame
df = pd.concat(keep, axis=1).T
df.set_index(['begin', 'end'], inplace=True)
df.head()
```

The result is:

```
                         values
begin      end                 
2014-09-21 2014-10-10  9.950167
2014-10-11 2014-10-30  9.392147
2014-09-01 2014-09-20  9.334021
2014-10-31 2014-11-19  7.725809
2014-08-12 2014-08-31  7.616417
```

Because i used a sine for the dummy data, the second highest window is right next to the highest, etc.

Btw, is this supposed to work in Pandas? Its results in a error for me:

```
del df[~(before | after)]
```

Comment: I think to delete selected rows you could use: `df.drop(df[(before | after)].index, inplace=True)`. But `df = df[~(before | after)]` looks more laconic.